# Python script to build least-cost paths between several polygons: How to speed up it?

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I created a python program which uses the function "CostPath" of ArcGIS to automatically build least-cost paths (LCPs) between several polygons contained in the shapefile "selected_patches.shp". My python program seems to work but it is much too slow. I must build 275493 LCPs. Unfortunately, I don't know how to speed up my program (I am a beginner in Python programming language and ArcGIS). Or is there another solution to calculate rapidly least-cost paths between several polygons with ArcGIS (I use ArcGIS 10.1) ? Here is my code:

```
# Import system modules
 import arcpy
 from arcpy import env
 from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

 # Overwrite outputs
 arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

 # Set the workspace
 arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\LCP"

 # Set the extent environment
 arcpy.env.extent = "costs.tif"


rowsInPatches_start = arcpy.SearchCursor("selected_patches.shp") 

for rowStart in rowsInPatches_start:        

ID_patch_start = rowStart.getValue("GRIDCODE") 

expressionForSelectInPatches_start = "GRIDCODE=%s" % (ID_patch_start) ## Define SQL expression for the fonction Select Layer By Attribute

# Process: Select Layer By Attribute in Patches_start
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("selected_patches.shp", "Selected_patch_start", expressionForSelectInPatches_start)

 # Process: Cost Distance
outCostDist=CostDistance("Selected_patch_start", "costs.tif", "", "outCostLink.tif")

# Save the output 
outCostDist.save("outCostDist.tif")

rowsInSelectedPatches_end = arcpy.SearchCursor("selected_patches.shp") 

for rowEnd in rowsInSelectedPatches_end:

    ID_patch_end = rowEnd.getValue("GRIDCODE") 

    expressionForSelectInPatches_end = "GRIDCODE=%s" % (ID_patch_end) ## Define SQL expression for the fonction Select Layer By Attribute

    # Process: Select Layer By Attribute in Patches_end
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("selected_patches.shp", "Selected_patch_end", expressionForSelectInPatches_end)

    # Process: Cost Path
    outCostPath = CostPath("Selected_patch_end", "outCostDist.tif", "outCostLink.tif", "EACH_ZONE","FID")

    # Save the output
    outCostPath.save('P_' +  str(int(ID_patch_start)) + '_' + str(int(ID_patch_end)) + ".tif")

    # Writing in file .txt
    outfile=open('P_' +  str(int(ID_patch_start)) + '_' + str(int(ID_patch_end)) + ".txt", "w")
    rowsTxt = arcpy.SearchCursor('P_' +  str(int(ID_patch_start)) + '_' + str(int(ID_patch_end)) + ".tif")
    for rowTxt in rowsTxt:
        value = rowTxt.getValue("Value")
        count = rowTxt.getValue("Count")
        pathcost = rowTxt.getValue("PATHCOST")
        startrow = rowTxt.getValue("STARTROW")
        startcol = rowTxt.getValue("STARTCOL")
        print value, count, pathcost, startrow, startcol
        outfile.write(str(value) + " " + str(count) + " " + str(pathcost) + " " + str(startrow) + " " + str(startcol) + "\n")
    outfile.close()
```

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The speed it takes to write to disc vs calculating your cost can be a bottleneck, consider adding a thread to handle all of your writes.

This:

```
for rowTxt in rowsTxt:
        value = rowTxt.getValue("Value")
        count = rowTxt.getValue("Count")
        pathcost = rowTxt.getValue("PATHCOST")
        startrow = rowTxt.getValue("STARTROW")
        startcol = rowTxt.getValue("STARTCOL")
        print value, count, pathcost, startrow, startcol
        outfile.write(str(value) + " " + str(count) + " " + str(pathcost) + " " + str(startrow) + " " + str(startcol) + "\n")
```

Can be converted into  a thread function by making rowsTxt a global variable, and having your thread write to disk from rowsTxt.
After you complete all of your processing you can have an additional global boolean so that your thread function can end when you are done writing everything and you can close your thread.

Example thread function I currently use:

```
import threading
class ThreadExample:
   def __init__(self):
      self.receiveThread = None

   def startRXThread(self):
      self.receiveThread = threading.Thread(target = self.receive)
      self.receiveThread.start()

   def stopRXThread(self):
      if self.receiveThread is not None:
         self.receiveThread.__Thread__stop()
         self.receiveThread.join()
         self.receiveThread = None

   def receive(self):
       while true:
          #do stuff for the life of the thread
          #in my case, I listen on a socket for data
          #and write it out
```

So for your case, you could add a class variable to the thread class

```
self.rowsTxt
```

and then update your receive to check self.rowsTxt, and if it is not empty, handle it as u do in the code snippet i took from you above. After you handle it, set self.rowsTxt back to None. You could update your threads self.rowsTxt with your main function as it gets rowsTxt. Consider using a buffer like list for self.rowsTxt so you don't miss writing anything.

Answer (score 1):

The most immediate change you can make to significant improve speed would be to switch to [data access cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000008000000) (e.g. `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()`).  To illustrate, I ran a benchmark test a while back to see the data access cursors perform compared to the old cursors.

The attached figure shows the results of a benchmark test on the new da method UpdateCursor versus the old UpdateCursor method. Essentially, the benchmark test performs the following workflow:

1. Create random points (10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000)
2. Randomly sample from a normal distribution and add value to a new
   column in the random points attribute table with a cursor
3. Run 5 iterations of each random point scenario for both the new and
   old UpdateCursor methods and write the mean value to lists
4. Plot the results

[image]

---

```
import arcpy, os, numpy, time
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

outws = r'C:\temp'
fc = os.path.join(outws, 'randomPoints.shp')

iterations = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000]
old = []
new = []

meanOld = []
meanNew = []

for x in iterations:
    arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management(outws, 'randomPoints', '', '', x)
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, 'randFloat', 'FLOAT')

    for y in range(5):

        # Old method ArcGIS 10.0 and earlier
        start = time.clock()

        rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)

        for row in rows:
            # generate random float from normal distribution
            s = float(numpy.random.normal(100, 10, 1))
            row.randFloat = s
            rows.updateRow(row)

        del row, rows

        end = time.clock()
        total = end - start
        old.append(total)

        del start, end, total

        # New method 10.1 and later
        start = time.clock()

        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['randFloat']) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                # generate random float from normal distribution
                s = float(numpy.random.normal(100, 10, 1))
                row[0] = s
                cursor.updateRow(row)

        end = time.clock()
        total = end - start
        new.append(total)
        del start, end, total
    meanOld.append(round(numpy.mean(old),4))
    meanNew.append(round(numpy.mean(new),4))

#######################
# plot the results

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(iterations, meanNew, label = 'New (da)')
plt.plot(iterations, meanOld, label = 'Old')
plt.title('arcpy.da.UpdateCursor -vs- arcpy.UpdateCursor')
plt.xlabel('Random Points')
plt.ylabel('Time (minutes)')
plt.legend(loc = 2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks very much Aaron for your answer. I don't know if it's correct but, in the code above, I replaced `rowsInPatches_start = arcpy.SearchCursor("selected_patches.shp")` by `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("selected_patches.shp",("*")) as rowsInPatches_start:` and `ID_patch_start = rowStart.getValue("GRIDCODE")` by `ID_patch_start = int(rowStart[3])`. Unfortunately, I don't know why my script is yet too long. Thanks for your help.